# Maven dependencies for Hadoop: MiniDFSCluster & MiniMRCluster

Tags: unit-testing, hadoop, hadoop2

I want to implement a maven project, that helps me unit test a Hadoop MapReduce job. My biggest problem is defining the Maven dependencies to be able to make use of the test classes:  MiniDFSCluster & MiniMRCluster.

I am using Hadoop 2.4.1. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guess I figured it out. In your Maven pom file, first add a new repository:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>cloudera</id>
        <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Then add the following to your project dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-auth</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-cdh4.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-test</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-cdh4.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-cdh4.3.0</version>
    <classifier>tests</classifier>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-cdh4.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-cdh4.3.0</version>
    <classifier>tests</classifier>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

In case someone is interested to get the whole project (unit test for the famous WordCount MapReduce job, I am willing to share it)

Comment: It is sufficient to include only hadoop-minicluster:

`<dependency><groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId><artifactId>hadoop-minicluster</artifactId><version>2.7.0</version></dependency>`

Answer (score 6):

In case someone else is still searchinf for an answer:

MiniMRCluster is now deprecated.

You can get MiniDFSCluster and MiniMRCluster in the dependency (shown for Gradle)

```
compile group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-minicluster', version: '2.7.2'
```

The dependency is basically just a pom file that lists out the dependencies in this package. For those who want to look this up, MiniDFSCluster is in the artifact `hadoop-hdfs:tests`

You don't have to use the dependencies from the Cloudera repository